# Cannot find route to JSON file on AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table_id').DataTable({
                "ajax" : "../personas.json",
                "columns" : [
                    {personas : "id"},
                    {personas : "nombre"},
                    {personas : "apellido"},
                    {personas : "email"},
                    {personas : "confirmado"}
                ]
            });
});
```

But everytime I refresh the page, I get an 404 error telling me it can't find the personas.json file, and I tried every way of putting it, it's one directory up from the code.

Screenshot:

[image]

How can I get there?

Comment: You need to configure your server to serve that file, then use an absolute path to it.

Comment: its relative to your html file, not the script file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using `express` here as you have `node_modules` and `package.json`, please leave a comment if I am wrong, do the following:

- Add directory and name it `public`
- Move your `json` file inside it
- In your `app.js` (which I believe it is your main JS file) make sure you have the following:

  ```
  app.use(express.static('public'))
  ```
- change your code `"ajax" : "/personas.json",`

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {

          $('#table_id').DataTable({
              "ajax" : "/personas.json",
              ...
          });
  });
  ```

More Info for serving static files could be found [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Hello, msoliman! Thank you for your response, it worked, but I had to change the ajax part to this: "ajax" : {"url":"/personas.json", "dataSrc":""}, because the other way was throwing a "cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error. The thing is, now the table has a message saying "No data available in table". Do you know what might be causing this?